# get height of a tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView between a label which is on top (constraints: align center x, align top to 20).

A button is on the bottom (constraints: align center x, align bottom to 50).

And the tableView is aligned between those two objects by top/bottom to 20.

I am trying to read out the height of the tableView, because depending which device I use the height should differ?
But if I use in my code the following, I always get the same height for the tableView.

The print result is always 616.

What am I missing/not understanding correctly?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(tableView.frame.size.height)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think autolayout handles it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(tableView.frame.size.height)
}
```

The reason that you see two different values printed is because this method is called right after viewdidload and once again after all the auto layout or auto resizing calculations on the views have been applied. Meaning the method viewDidLayoutSubviews is called every time the view size changes and the view layout has been recalculated.

For more info on this refer to
[Apple documentation on viewdidlayoutsubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)

Comment: I understand now. But I want to calculate the row height of the cells based on the height of the tableView. To fill up the space entirely, no matter which device I'm using, but the calculation seems to be very "late", whenever the view appears I can see that the cells have a different height, then it gets calculated, and then it changes. any idea how I can get the height earlier?

Comment: can you share the code where you are giving height for cells?

Comment: well I just pasted my code now into the viewWillLayoutSubviews: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.rowHeight = tableView.frame.size.height / CGFloat(playerNames.count)
    }

Comment: or you can add tableView.frame.size.height / CGFloat(playerNames.count)  to heightforrowat delegate method of tableview, which i think would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

try getting your height in

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    print(tableView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: thanks! that helped. but for some reasons, I get now two print statements, one time the 616 again, and then the smaller number. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

When your view controller is created from a storyboard, all initial frames are equal to your storyboard selected ones, so they will be correct only to device selected in the storyboard

First time you can access real frames is after first `layoutSubviews`, so you need this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(tableView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Check out more about view lifecycle [here](https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5)

p.s. newer forget to call `super.` method when you're overriding something, you may break something easily. Unless the documentation says so or you're really knowing what you're doing